# Distributed retraining (TF & Google Coral)

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, transfer-learning, google-coral

Assuming I have tens of Google Coral devices doing object detection (using same trained model), every once in awhile we will retraining a device for new object (transfer learning), lets say this device is Coral1, now I wonder how would I transfer learning, what Coral1 learned to all devices (without the need to retrain those devices)?

for sure devices can be Google Coral or any other device

Answer (score 1):

Since what we are assuming is that, all the devices will inference on the same model at start,

whenever there is a new learning done by any device, the updated trained model should be pushed to all other devices, helping them to start recognizing the new objects.

Every device does not need to train individually, if we can maintain synchronization among the devices.

For further information, go through this [link](https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/edgetpu/retrain-detection/)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be "retraining a device", but rather retraining a model. Take a look at this guide on how to re-train a model:
https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/edgetpu/retrain-detection/

Once you've finished retraining a model, you can scp it into the other board and reload.